# Asking name once and storing it afterwards

Tags: java, android, string, android-intent, boolean

What I want is that when Activity starts first time, it first checks if nimiolemas is true. Since it just starts, then it can't be true. So, it will automatically starts new activity and also asks to get me info. In activity 2 person can type their name and when they press Ok, info will be sent back to activity one. Now, I don't know really how to change there Boolean to true and send that as well, so for now I told to change nimiolemas true before launching activity 2.

After pressing ok, it sends back to activity one and does the check again. Since it should be now true and also able to retrieve information about persons name, then it will go to true condition and print that name on screen in first activity. Now whenever program is launched, it will skip asking name and will straight show the person name :).

But it doesn't work exactly as I want. Before i put boolean, it actually went to second activity, but I couldn't get data so well. I have been working on solution for too long and I really appreciate help. If I find mistakes I can study from that more then searching on solution all over internet for next 10 hours :(.

I might have made some things very wrong, so please let me know and teach me! I really want to get better in this! So far I have done:

---

```
package viimane.voimalus;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainStuff extends Activity {

    String tyybinimi;
    TextView tere;

    Boolean nimiolemas;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        tere = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TERE);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, nimekysija.class);
        tyybinimi = i.getStringExtra("nimi");

        if (nimiolemas = true) {
            System.out.print(tyybinimi);
        } else {
            startActivity(i);
            nimiolemas = true;
            finish();
        }

    }
}
```

---

```
package viimane.voimalus;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
package viimane.voimalus;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class nimekysija extends Activity {

    Intent resultIntent;
    EditText nimi;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nimekysija);
        Button kysOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNimekysija);
        nimi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNimekysija);

        kysOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        String nimiS = nimi.getText().toString();


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.putExtra("nimi", nimiS);
                startActivity(new Intent("viimane.voimalus.MAIN"));
                finish();


            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `boolean`, you should be using [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Comment: how exactly? I watched it and seems way more complicated :/. I am still pretty new.

Comment: Look at the example code on how to get a `boolean` from the common preferences for your application. The second argument from `getBoolean()` is the default value for a stored preference if it hasn't been set and doesn't exist yet. `setBoolean()` will allow the preference to be stored even if the application is closed and reopened.

Comment: This way `nimiolemas` is unnecessary.

Comment: Hm... But Don't I still need to set if true and stuff? Or I can transfer just strings with that as well (Aka name) or what?

Comment: Any primitive datatype can be stored with them (`setString`,`getString`). I would create a boolean that would have a default false value, and then set it to true after setting the name.

Comment: I see. But shouldn't I still make then checking like if (boolean = true) { Don't ask name} else {ask name}?